# Double click selecting words separated by periods like "i.a."

Tags: wpf, textbox

My goal is to double click the entire part of "i.a." [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrZtm.png) however the default for WPF is it [selects each part of the string individually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mqk4Y.png)

Sample:

```xml
<TextBox>Reason for contact: i.a.</TextBox>
```

## What I've found so far

I've attempted to use `SpellCheck.CustomDictionaries`, word selection is unaffected by these.

Comment: There is some confusion. Are you looking for this functionality with the `TextBox` or the `RichTextBox`? Does the text formatting required? Is it required to use content with the different fonts, colors etc?

Comment: @Jackdaw I'm looking at both but I recognize that RichTextBox is very much different from TextBox with its TextPointer, so I'll create a new question dedicated to RichTextBox soon and edit this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one. It selects text part depending on caret position (which is `SelectionStart - 1`) from nearest left whitespace `' '` (or start of string) to nearest right one (or end of string).

```
private void OnMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is TextBox tb)
    {
        char[] chars = tb.Text.ToCharArray();

        int i;
        // Find nearest left whitespace or start of string
        for (i = tb.SelectionStart - 1; i >= 0 && chars[i] != ' '; i--);
        int selectionStart = i + 1;

        // Find nearest right whitespace or end of string
        for (i = tb.SelectionStart; i < chars.Length && chars[i] != ' '; i++);
        int selectionLength = i - selectionStart;
        
        tb.Select(selectionStart, selectionLength);
    }
}
```

[image]